# Convert js Select to Radio buttons?

Tags: jquery, select, radio-button, onchange

I'm trying to convert a Select menu with an onchange function to radio buttons.  But I'm no programmer. The example here has both sets, the Select working, the Radio's not. I *think* it might be a problem with the handling of the 'field_type'.

Link to the example - http://originscards.com/pledge/strip.php

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var field_type = { check: 0, group: 1 }; // Control Type
var c_iitem = { pledge: 0, pledge2: 1, pledge3: 2, pledge4: 3, shipping: 4 };

var s_aitem = [
{sz: 'pledge', ct: field_type.group, pledgeAmt: 12, qty: 0},
{sz: 'pledge2', ct: field_type.group, pledgeAmt: 17, qty: 0},
{sz: 'pledge3', ct: field_type.group, pledgeAmt: 29, qty: 0},
{sz: 'pledge4', ct: field_type.group, pledgeAmt: 41, qty: 0},       
{sz: 'shipping', ct: field_type.check, pledgeAmt: 0, qty: 0}
];

function UpdateQty(iitem)
{
var ctl = document.getElementById(s_aitem[iitem].sz);
if (s_aitem[iitem].ct == field_type.check)
{ s_aitem[iitem].qty = ctl.checked ? 1 : 0; }
else if (s_aitem[iitem].ct == field_type.group)
{
    if (iitem == c_iitem.pledge)
        s_aitem[c_iitem.pledge].qty = s_aitem[c_iitem.pledge2].qty = s_aitem[c_iitem.pledge3].qty = s_aitem[c_iitem.pledge4].qty = 0;                   

    i = parseInt(ctl.value, 4);
    if (i >= 0)
        s_aitem[iitem + i].qty = 1;
}
else // num
{ s_aitem[iitem].qty = (ctl.value == '' || isNaN(ctl.value)) ? 0 :   
parseInt(ctl.value, 10); }
}

function NewVal(iitem)
{
var i, pledgeAmt, shipping;
UpdateQty(iitem);
pledgeAmt = 0;
for (i = s_aitem.length; --i >= 0; )
    pledgeAmt += s_aitem[i].qty * s_aitem[i].pledgeAmt;
if (s_aitem[c_iitem.shipping].qty == 0)
    shipping = 0;
else
{
    shipping =      
    s_aitem[c_iitem.pledge].qty * 9 +
    s_aitem[c_iitem.pledge2].qty * 9 +
    s_aitem[c_iitem.pledge3].qty * 14 +
    s_aitem[c_iitem.pledge4].qty * 14 ;
}

document.getElementById('pledgeAmt').innerHTML = pledgeAmt;
document.getElementById('shipAmt').innerHTML = shipping;
document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = pledgeAmt + shipping;
}

function UpdatePrices()
{
UpdateQty(c_iitem.pledge);  
NewVal(c_iitem.shipping);
}

</script>

</head>
<body>

<form name="form1">

<!-- SELECT WORKS -->    
<select size=1 name="pledge" id="pledge" onchange="NewVal(c_iitem.pledge);" 
onkeyup="NewVal(c_iitem.pledge);">
<option value="-1" selected> </option>
<option value="0">pledgeA</option>
<option value="1">pledgeB</option>
<option value="2">pledgeC</option>
<option value="3">pledgeD</option>
</select>

<!-- RADIO DOES NOT -->    
<input name="pledge" id="pledge" type="radio" value="-l" style="display:none" checked>  
<input name="pledge" id="pledge" type="radio" value="0" onchange="NewVal(c_iitem.pledge);" onkeyup="NewVal(c_iitem.pledge);">Pledge A<br/>    
<input name="pledge" id="pledge" type="radio" value="1" onchange="NewVal(c_iitem.pledge);" onkeyup="NewVal(c_iitem.pledge);">Pledge B<br/>
<input name="pledge" id="pledge" type="radio" value="2" onchange="NewVal(c_iitem.pledge);" onkeyup="NewVal(c_iitem.pledge);">Pledge C<br/>
<input name="pledge" id="pledge" type="radio" value="3" onchange="NewVal(c_iitem.pledge);" onkeyup="NewVal(c_iitem.pledge);">Pledge D<br/>

<input id="shipping_us" type="radio" name="shipping" value="-1" checked onchange="NewVal(c_iitem.shipping);" onkeyup="NewVal(c_iitem.shipping);">
No Shipping<br/>
<input id="shipping" type="radio" name="shipping" value="0" onchange="NewVal(c_iitem.shipping);" onkeyup="NewVal(c_iitem.shipping);">
Shipping

Pledge $<span id="pledgeAmt">0</span>
Shipping $<span id="shipAmt">0</span>
Total $<span id="total">0</span>
</form>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">UpdatePrices();</script>
```

Comment: StackOverflow users do not need Money to help you. They will help you anyway if they know the answer. ;)

Comment: convert how exactly ?

Comment: Ha ok thanks Ahaan.  I need the radio's to send a value to the NewVal function in the same way the Select does.  Isn't happening at the moment

Comment: @RickDavidson No problem; good luck with the issue! I'm not experienced with this, otherwise I would have tried to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would start by changing the ID field you have to use seperate names, currently the only byID field you'll get with "pledge" is the selector element

```
<form name="form1">

<!-- SELECT WORKS -->    
<select size=1 name="pledge" id="pledge" onchange="NewVal(c_iitem.pledge);" onkeyup="NewVal(c_iitem.pledge);">
<option value="-1" selected> </option>
<option value="0">pledgeA</option>
<option value="1">pledgeB</option>
<option value="2">pledgeC</option>
<option value="3">pledgeD</option>
</select>
<hr />
<!-- RADIO DOES NOT -->    
<input type="radio" name="pledge" id="pledge" value="-l" style="display:none" checked>  
<input name="pledge" id="pledge" type="radio" value="0" onchange="NewVal(c_iitem.pledge);" onkeyup="NewVal(c_iitem.pledge);">Pledge A<br/>
<input name="pledge" id="pledge2" type="radio" value="1" onchange="NewVal(c_iitem.pledge);" onkeyup="NewVal(c_iitem.pledge);">Pledge B<br/>
<input name="pledge" id="pledge3" type="radio" value="2"  onchange="NewVal(c_iitem.pledge);" onkeyup="NewVal(c_iitem.pledge);">Pledge C<br/>
<input name="pledge" id="pledge" type="radio" value="3" onchange="NewVal(c_iitem.pledge);" onkeyup="NewVal(c_iitem.pledge);">Pledge D<br/>
<hr />
<input id="shipping_us" type="radio" name="shipping" value="-1" checked onchange="NewVal(c_iitem.shipping);" onkeyup="NewVal(c_iitem.shipping);">No Shipping<br/>
<input id="shipping" type="radio" name="shipping" value="0" onchange="NewVal(c_iitem.shipping);" onkeyup="NewVal(c_iitem.shipping);">Shipping
<hr />

Pledge $<span id="pledgeAmt">0</span>
<hr />
Shipping $<span id="shipAmt">0</span>
<hr /> 
Total $<span id="total">0</span>
</form>
```

2 of your radio buttons use the "pledge" id as well

EDIT: One way to select the object that an event happened on is to select by class and then use the $(this) jquery selector

```
$(".clickMe").click(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
});
```

Comment: Aha so the problem is the 'document.getElementById'?  Sorry, how would I correct this to use separate names?

Comment: If you're doing a click event, one of the things you can do is use $(this) which will reference the object that just clicked on with out the need to check by ID; I'll edit in some code to my answer

Comment: Only if you are using jQuery. The dollar signs in his example are actually for money values ;)

Comment: Well consider me blind =P

Answer (score 0):

I would actually simplify it even further. If you aren't doing anything with the IDs outside of the NewVal functionality, you can remove the ID attribute. It does need to be unique per element if you are using it. However, keeping with the standard JavaScript syntax you are using, you can bind an event to all items named "pledge" by looping through the object collection from getElementsByName and binding the onChange event. Then, in an anonymous function for it, reference the element or the value, depending on your need:

```
function NewVal(val) {
    document.getElementById('example').value=val;
}
function NewValElement(ele){
    document.getElementById('example').value=ele.outerHTML;
}
var pledges = document.getElementsByName('pledge');
for (var i = 0;i<pledges.length;i++) {
    // do something with value
    /*pledges[i].onchange=function() {
        NewVal(this.value);
    };*/
    // do something with element
    pledges[i].onchange=function() {
        NewValElement(this);
    };
}
```

This will make it easier to manage the event because you don't have to add the onchange to each. You don't need a keydown or anything either because the onchange is fired when the value changes for a select option or a radio group.

Fiddle for working example: http://jsfiddle.net/9qfst/1/

The input shows the HTML of the element to show you that it has the element triggering the event.

**Update** I forked the fiddle and cleaned it up a bit to make the functionality behave the way I think you were looking for the sample to work. I looked at your full site too and see what you are trying to do. Now, I just kept what you had, more or less, and rewrote pieces to clean it up and make it work. It's all still using raw JavaScript, not a framework. I also have the script going in at the bottom of the body element, just before close, so I don't have an onLoad event or anything. I am also not calling the UpdatePrices for this example as it looked like it was just setting everything to 0.

Now, this could be cleaned up even more, from what I can see in what you are doing, and there are alternative ways to do this, and also ways to use jQuery to simplify some of this. However, this seems to be working pretty well, from what I can tell. The only thing I didn't do is add in the AddOns that you have on your site.

Check this out and let me know if you have more questions: http://jsfiddle.net/92DJ6/2/

Comment: I don't know how you whipped that up so quickly but thank you, it means a lot.  A week of frustration solved in 5 minutes.  I'll test it out shortly

Comment: Let me know if you have questions on it. I can help explain or complete it if you need more pointers or assistance.

Comment: Ugh. I can tweak your example but struggling to integrate into my project, just not my skill.  I'm trying to build a calculator for Kickstarter and running low on time, interested in helping complete it?  I could really use a pro. Don't think there is much to do, would be happy to cover your time.  Here is progrss so far - http://originscards.com/pledge/ . Is just the top deck of (image) radios I can't patch in.

Comment: I updated my answer. I didn't fully build what you have on the live site, but made the example work with a decent size alternative method. Let me know if you have more questions or still have trouble getting it in your project. I think the new fiddle is a little clearer.

Comment: Wow, that's beautiful Daved, thank's so much.  Yes I'm sure it could be a lot more elegant than what I have, thank you so much for tidying it up for me. Life saver. Send me your email if you like